# Snakemake, missing input exception error for rule_all

Tags: snakemake

I am wondering why I keep getting the missing input exception error for rule_all?

Due to the particularity of my situation, where the output of "myrule" uses different combinations of wildcards, I have decided to define list of output files separately -- outside of any rules.

When I look at the "missing files" paths, I see that all the missing files path match up with all the paths in output_list. Hence, I don't comprehend where the errors are coming from.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

```
output_list = []

for r in range(1,12):

    for wv in [1,2]:

    output_list.append(Path(os.path.abspath('data/fov/{fov}/z/{z}/original_size')).joinpath(f'{wv}nm/{r:02}' + '_{fov:03}_{z:02}.tiff'))
    
    
print(output_list)

rule all:
    input:
        expand(Path(os.path.abspath('data/fov/{fov}/z/{z}/original_size/{wv}nm/{round_num:02}_{fov:03}_{z:02}.tiff')), fov=range(0,5), z=range(1,8), wv=[1,2], round_num=range(1,12))

rule myrule:
    input:
        Path('data/fov/{fov}/z/{z}/pp.tif')
    output:        
        output_list
    shell:
        "python split.py -f {fov} -z {z}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem with your `Snakefile`, but rather with what you are expecting vs. what you are describing in your Snakefile.
The way it is setup, the Missing input exception cannot be fixed:

- `rule all` has to rely on `rule myrule` to provide all input files
- `rule myrule` does not have all the `output` defined by `output_list` which `rule all` requires as `input` (the two lists, rules.all.input and rules.myrule.output) do not match

Take a look at your `Snakefile` again (formatted using `snakefmt`):

```py
output_list = []
for r in range(1, 12):
    for wv in [1, 2]:
        output_list.append(
            "data/fov/{fov}/z/{z}/original_size"
            + f"/{wv}nm/{r:02}"
            + "_{fov:03}_{z:02}.tiff"
        )


rule all:
    input:
        expand(
            "data/fov/{fov}/z/{z}/original_size/{wv}nm/{round_num:02}_{fov:03}_{z:02}.tiff",
            fov=range(0, 5),
            z=range(1, 8),
            wv=[1, 2],
            round_num=range(1, 12),
        ),


rule myrule:
    input:
        "data/fov/{fov}/z/{z}/pp.tif",
    output:
        output_list,
    shell:
        "python split.py -f {fov} -z {z}"


from pprint import pprint
print(f"Number of outputs from rule myrule: {len(rules.myrule.output)}")
print(f"Number of inputs for rule all: {len(rules.all.input)}")
```

I've added the last 3 lines to show you that the inputs/outputs don't match up:

```py
Number of outputs from rule myrule: 22
Number of inputs for rule all: 770
```

So either your MWE is not correct or you need to rethink your structure. Maybe your list expansion is incorrect, but that's just speculation at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In rule `all` you are misplacing the quotes and closing brackets:

```
os.path.abspath('data/.../{wv}nm, Raw/..._{z:02}.tiff')
                               ^^^
```

Comment: Hi Dariober, thanks for pointing that out! But this was actually a typo when i tried simplifying the code on Stackoverflow. So the missing input exception error is still here :/

Comment: I suspect there is some simple mismatch. Try to simplify your code until it works and you see what's wrong. You have quite a lot packed in a single line.